# proving the limit when x tends to +,- infinity of arctan(x)

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification

[image]

Would love if someone could look at my proof.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine to me, every value you chose is well defined during the entire proof.
I would denote though that when you let $\epsilon\ge\pi/2$ ,

you want to keep the $\ge$ , as concluding that:

$\pi/4<\pi/2<\epsilon$

is false when choosing $\epsilon=\pi/2$

Comment: Thank you very much!